# Bolt CMS: Can contenttype title be generated based on other field values?

Tags: bolt-cms

I would like to create a contenttype that has select fields for things like 'month of year' and 'type of product' and have the title field be auto generated based on the values of these two fields.

This is because the two select field values are descriptive enough, and I would like to reduce the amount of repetitive typing of the same information the end user of the CMS may have to do to make a title show up in the admin interface instead of (no content …) or (no title …) due to no title or excerpt.

I have tried using a hidden field for the title with a default option and a uses option like for slug but couldn't make it work.

Is there a way to achieve a dynamically generated title based on other field values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved using the title_format option like `title_format: [month, type]` in the contenttype definition.

Answer (score 0):

It just shows the title in the admin, but doesn't save it in the database and public folder!